# Understanding an Intermediate Value theorem problem

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

it's nice to talk to you guys again, and ooh—is that a new haircut? I love that on you!

I have a question regarding Intermediate Value theorem. I feel like I understand the concept but I'm having trouble understanding a particular problem. I'm not what this problem is asking me to do, perhaps someone could clear it up for me. It reads as follows:

Show that if $f$ is continuous on [0, 1] and $0 \le f(x) \le 1$ for all x on [0, 1], then there exists at least one point c in [0, 1] at which f(c) = c. HINT: Apply the Intermediate Value theorem to the function $g(x) = x – f(x)$.

Obviously the last part is important, but I don't know how it all fits. This seems fairly different than proving that there lies a root of a function between two points.

Comment: Note $g(0)\le 0$ and $g(1)\ge 0$.

Comment: What is $g(0)$ and $g(1)$?

Comment: This question has been asked before: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/557468/continuous-map-from-0-1-to-0-1/561358#561358

Comment: Understanding what $f(c)=c$ implies is the key to understanding this problem. Also, try using $g(x)=f(x)-x$ and ask yourself, why am I subtracting $x$?

Answer (score 0):

You want to prove that $g(x)=0$ for some $x$. Can you apply the intermediate value theorem? Which interval would you choose?